# How to save the string, one word per column in Python?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

I'm scraping the names of massage therapists along with their addresses from a directory. The addresses are all being saved into the CSV in one column for the whole string, but the title/name of each therapist is being saved one word per column over 2 or 3 columns.

What do I need to do in order to get the string that's being extracted to save in one column, like the addresses are being saved?  (The top two lines of code are example html from the page, the next set of code is the extract from the script targeting this element)

```
<span class="name">
    <img src="/images/famt-placeholder-sm.jpg" class="thumb" alt="Tiffani D Abraham"> Tiffani D Abraham</span>


import mechanize
from lxml import html
import csv
import io
from time import sleep

def save_products (products, writer):

    for product in products:

        for price in product['prices']:
            writer.writerow([ product["title"].encode('utf-8') ])
            writer.writerow([ price["contact"].encode('utf-8') ])
            writer.writerow([ price["services"].encode('utf-8') ])

f_out = open('mtResult.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(f_out)

links = ["https://www.amtamassage.org/findamassage/results.html?match=exact&l=NY","https://www.amtamassage.org/findamassage/results.html?match=exact&l=NY&PageIndex=2&PageSize=10","https://www.amtamassage.org/findamassage/results.html?match=exact&l=NY&PageIndex=3&PageSize=10","https://www.amtamassage.org/findamassage/results.html?match=exact&l=NY&PageIndex=4&PageSize=10","https://www.amtamassage.org/findamassage/results.html?match=exact&l=NY&PageIndex=5&PageSize=10","https://www.amtamassage.org/findamassage/results.html?match=exact&l=NY&PageIndex=6&PageSize=10","https://www.amtamassage.org/findamassage/results.html?match=exact&l=NY&PageIndex=7&PageSize=10", "https://www.amtamassage.org/findamassage/results.html?match=exact&l=NY&PageIndex=8&PageSize=10", "https://www.amtamassage.org/findamassage/results.html?match=exact&l=NY&PageIndex=9&PageSize=10", "https://www.amtamassage.org/findamassage/results.html?match=exact&l=NY&PageIndex=10&PageSize=10" ]

br = mechanize.Browser()    

for link in links:

    print(link)
    r = br.open(link)

    content = r.read()

    products = []        
    tree = html.fromstring(content)        
    product_nodes = tree.xpath('//ul[@class="famt-results"]/li')

    for product_node in product_nodes:

        product = {}


        price_nodes = product_node.xpath('.//a')

        product['prices'] = []
        for price_node in price_nodes:

            price = {}
            try:
                product['title'] = product_node.xpath('.//span[1]/text()')[0]

            except:
                product['title'] = ""

            try:
                price['services'] = price_node.xpath('./span[2]/text()')[0]

            except:
                price['services'] = ""

            try:
                price['contact'] = price_node.xpath('./span[3]/text()')[0]

            except:
                price['contact'] = ""

            product['prices'].append(price)
        products.append(product)
    save_products(products, writer)

f_out.close()
```

Comment: please add part of your data to your question, it will be easier to see what you mean.

Comment: @LetzerWille This is the page I am extracting from: `https://www.amtamassage.org/findamassage/results.html?match=exact&l=NY` - the csv that's being generated is 3 rows per therapist, with the order descending from name, address, specialisations.  The address and specialisations are saved into the column A only, but the names are spread across columns B, C and D, with one word in each.
I've posted the entire script now.

Comment: I've realised that the problem is that the data for `product["title"]` is a string instead of a list (unlike the data for `services` and `contact` which are both lists).  I know I need to change something that is causing it to expect a list instead of a string, but I'm not sure which part of the code needs to be adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive if this solves the issue you were having, but either way there are a few improvements and modifications you might be interested in.

For example, since each link varies by a page index you can loop through the links easily rather than copying all 50 down to a list.  Each therapist per page also has their own index, so you can also loop through the xpaths for each therapist's information.

```
#import modules
import mechanize
from lxml import html
import csv
import io

#open browser
br = mechanize.Browser()

#create file headers
titles = ["NAME"]
services = ["TECHNIQUE(S)"]
contacts = ["CONTACT INFO"]

#loop through all 50 webpages for therapist data
for link_index in range(1,50):

    link = "https://www.amtamassage.org/findamassage/results.html?match=exact&l=NY&PageIndex=" + str(link_index) + "&PageSize=10"
    r = br.open(link)
    page = r.read()      
    tree = html.fromstring(page)        

    #loop through therapist data for each therapist per page
    for therapist_index in range(1,10):

        #store names
        title = tree.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/ul[1]/li[' + str(therapist_index) + ']/a/span[1]/text()')
        titles.append(" ".join(title))

        #store techniques and convert to unicode
        service = tree.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/ul[1]/li[' + str(therapist_index) + ']/a/span[2]/text()')
        try:
            services.append(service[0].encode("utf-8"))
        except:
            services.append(" ")

        #store contact info and convert to unicode
        contact = tree.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/ul[1]/li[' + str(therapist_index) + ']/a/span[3]/text()')
        try:
            contacts.append(contact[0].encode("utf-8"))
        except:
            contacts.append(" ")

#open file to write to
f_out = open('mtResult.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(f_out)

#get rows in correct format
rows = zip(titles, services, contacts)

#write csv line by line
for row in rows:
    writer.writerow(row)
f_out.close()
```

The script loops through all 50 links on the provided webpage, and seems to be scraping all relevant information for each therapist if provided.  Finally, it prints all the data to a csv with all data stored under respective columns for 'Name', 'Technique(s)', and 'Contact Info' if this is what you were originally struggling with.

Hope this helps!